# Laravel in_arrary display tags

Tags: laravel

I'm probably overthinking this one... I started learning Laravel the other day. I've been following a simple "Blog" type project video on YouTube.

I slightly dived away from some aspects of the video. Here I have created "Tags" for the blog posts.
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G99QQ.png)

What I'm trying to do is make it so if the "Important!" tag is used, that is displayed with the Bootstrap "badge-warning" whereas the rest of the tags will be using the class "badge-primary"

Heres what I've whipped up so far:

Tags:

```xml
@foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
    @if (in_array('Important!', $post->tags))
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">{{ $tag }}</span>
    @else
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{ $tag }}</span>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

As you can see In the screenshot, this displays all tags for that post with the warning class. Which makes sense, because that's what I'm telling it to do! I'm just having a blank moment haha.

Comment: `if(in_array('Important!', $post->tags))` checks if there is an 'Important!' tag associated with the post, not if the tag itself is 'Important!'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```xml
@foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-{{$tag == 'Important!' ? 'warning' : 'primary'}}">
        {{ $tag }}
    </span>       
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are checking in the original array if the *important!* tag exists. Since it exists, it's every time evaluated to true thus, each tag has the `badge-warning` class.
You should only check the current iterated tag. I have modified your code to reflect this change
Try:

```
  @foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
     @if ('Important!'== $tag))
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">{{ $tag }}</span>
      @else
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">{{ $tag }}</span>
      @endif
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This option does work, and is very close to something I tried earlier! I've marked the above option as the correct answer but this is also great. Thanks.

Comment: I have explained you the issue and not refactor your code to keep the answer focused on the issue